# C programming: testing oversized shift

Tags: c

Negative and oversized bit shifts are undefined behaviour. But I need to do positive/negative shifts in many places of my code, so I wrote a generic function for that:

```
uint64_t shift_bit(uint64_t b, int i)
{
    // detect oversized shift
    assert(-63 <= i && i <= 63);
    return i >= 0 ? b << i : b >> -i;
}
```

That takes care of negative shifts. But what about oversized shift?

**Is a C compiler allowed to optimize away the `assert()`?** (Or to replace it with `assert(true)`, which has the same effect).

**Is there a way to code around it?**

PS: Please base your answers only on what the standard guarantees, not on what your specific compiler does. My program needs to be 100% portable, as it gets compiled for many different platforms, and with many different compilers.

Comment: In what way(s) does this not handle oversized shifts?

Comment: According to the standard, a C compiler is allowed to assume the absence od undefined behavious, and to replace -63 <= i && i <= 63 by 'true'.

Comment: why would a compiler have undefined behavior in evaluating this expression "-63 <= i && i <= 63" ?

Comment: @VikramSingh it is pretty amazing what compilers can do w/ undefined behavior read [Undefined Behavior Consequences Contest Winners](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/767) to get a better idea.

Comment: [kcc](https://github.com/kframework/c-semantics) or maybe [STACK](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/970) may be an alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: The short answer is no. So long as NDEBUG is not defined, the `assert` must generate an error if `i` is not in the range it tests for.  The use of `i` as a shift count does not change that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

assert() is replaced to "nothing" on release.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(exp) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(exp) /*implementation*/
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want: assert = no-op when NDEBUG is defined. What I want is to make sure the assert is not optimized away or replaced by assert(true) in **debug mode**. The problem is that the C standard allows compilers to assume the absence of undefined behavious and replace -63 <= i && i <= 63 by 'true'.

Comment: @lucasart As I know, compiler's optimize should not change the meaning of code. "-63 <= i && i <= 63" is not undefined hebaviour (shift operation is..).